# Why when I return a string value from database, it gives me a string with 'http://localhost:8000' in it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I save a featured photo to my public/uploads/post and save a string with the photo name to my database. And when I want to delete it, I can't do it. Then I track the error and just realize when I return the value of my photo field in the table, it gives me the photo name with `http://localhost:8000` in it

This is my code :

```
$featured = $request->featured;
$featured_new_name = time() . $featured->getClientOriginalName();
$featured->move('uploads/post', $featured_new_name);
$post = Post::create([
    'post_title' => $request->post_title,
    'post_content' => $request->post_content,
    'featured' => 'uploads/post/' . $featured_new_name,
    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
    'post_slug' => str_slug($request->post_title)
]);
```

Then when i try to return it with die() :

```
die($post->featured);
```

It give me this result :

```
http://localhost:8000/uploads/post/1545856404foto.jpg
```

When i die() it, before save to the database, it work fine :

```
die($featured_new_name);
```

The Result :

```
1545856533foto.jpg
```

I return another value after i save to database, and it work fine :

```
die($post->post_title);
```

The Result :

```
asdsadadsada
```

So, before i save to the database, the photo name work fine. But after i save to database and return it, the photo name mess up. That the database work like that? Or it is an error?

Comment: Are you using some trait in the class to implement featured attribute?

Comment: check the database itself. does photo name appear there correctly?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze the database work fine, i just forgot that i have accessor in my model. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your system has some extra programmatic logic in it that either

1. Adds `http://localhost:8000` to the value before saving it
2. Add `http://localhost:8000` to the variable (via a magic `__get`er) before returning the value of `post_title`

This may be something that's in your `Post` class itself, or may be happening in an [event listener](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-events-getting-started).  Unfortunately, without more information about your system it's impossible to say for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i just realize that i have an accessor in my model. It work fine now

Answer (score 0):

try to save just the name of the photo :

```
'featured' => $featured_new_name,
```

and instead use the full photo address in the href attribute of your img tag.

Comment: The problem is i forget that i have an accessor in my model. But thanks for the help